# Merge two partitions

Tags: linux, filesystems, partition, lvm

I have a question, how do I move my `/dev/mapper/datos-datos_lv` so I can use that space on `/`? I want to use the space from `/dev/mapper/datos on the`/` filesystem.

```
df -h
Filesystem          Size    Used    Avail   Use%    Mounted on
/dev/sda1           92G     5.8G    82G     7%      /
devtmpfs            1.9G    0       1.9G    0%      /dev
tmpfs               1.9G    140K    1.9G    1%      /dev/shm
tmpfs               1.9G    41M     1.9G    3%      /run
tmpfs               1.9G    0       1.9G    0%      /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mapper/datos   296GB   63M     281G    1%      /opt
tmpfs               379M    28K     379M    1%      /run/user/1000
```

What I want to achieve is:

```
df -h
Filesystem          Size    Used    Avail   Use%    Mounted on
/dev/sda1           388G    5.8G    82G     7%      /
devtmpfs            1.9G    0       1.9G    0%      /dev
tmpfs               1.9G    140K    1.9G    1%      /dev/shm
tmpfs               1.9G    41M     1.9G    3%      /run
tmpfs               1.9G    0       1.9G    0%      /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs               379M    28K     379M    1%      /run/user/1000
```

Is there any way to get 388G on `/`?

Comment: Your question is not clear. What do you want to do? Do you want to use the space *from `/dev/mapper/datos`* on the `/` filesystem?

Comment: Yes Gilles! That's what I need. :#

Answer (score 0):

If you are on / you can't unmout this partition since you are using it. Try booting from an external source say a cd or usb with something like gparted: http://gparted.sourceforge.net/livecd.php

Access terminal and run, assuming the partition once the live cd is mounted is 1, if not replace it with the correct partition `df -h` may help:

```
umount /dev/sda1
mount /dev/mapper/datos-datos_lv /
```

Comment: The question is vague, but so is your answer. What do you think the question means? What do you propose to achieve?

Comment: English is not my first language! Sorry haha. I want to be able to use that space on /. So for example I'd have a total of 388GB on /. Not sure if it's possible.

Comment: @Gilles I understood he is trying to mount `/dev/mapper/datos-datos_lv` on / and user that instead of the disk or partition he currently has on there. Is that right @xKurisu?

Answer (score -1):

You need to edit `/etc/fstab` and make sure you remove the mount point for your "datos" disk

```
umount /opt
mkdir /datos (for instance)
echo "/dev/mapper/datos-datos_lv /datos ext3 defaults 0 0" >> /etc/fstab
mount /datos
```

This is assuming you use ext3

Comment: The question is vague, but this does not make any sense given the `df` output.

Comment: English is not my first language! Sorry haha. I want to be able to use that space on /. So for example I'd have a total of 388GB on /. Not sure if it's possible.